# Method to count unread messages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I currently use this method to count unread messages for a user (self here):

```
def unread_messages_count
  number = 0
  conversations = Conversation.where {|conversation| conversation.user1 == self || conversation.user2 == self }
  conversations.each do |conversation|
    number += conversation.messages.select{|message| !message.read && (message.user != self) }.count
  end
  number
end
```

However, this seems highly inefficient to me since I'm iterating on every conversation found to look for unread messages.

Any input on how to make this method smarter will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

About your code:

- As a general rule, the imperative pattern `acc = 0; xs.each { |x| acc += f(x) }; total = acc` should be replaced by the functional expression `total = xs.reduce(0) { |acc, x| acc + f(x) }` or `total = xs.map { |x| f(x) }.reduce(0, :+)`. Given that Rails provides an `Enumerable#sum`, it can be simplified even more: `total = xs.map { |x| f(x) }.sum`.
- That said, this is not the way you do things in Rails, you should use [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). The code will be much faster (all the processing is performed by the database engine) and more reusable.

I'd write:

```
class User 
  has_many :conversations, ->(user) { Conversation.with_user(user) }
  has_many :messages, through: :conversations

  def unread_messages_count
    messages.not_sent_by(self).unread.count
  end
end

class Conversation
  scope :with_user, ->(user) { where("? IN (user1_id, user2_id)", user.id) }
end

class Message
  scope :unread, -> { where(read: false) }
  scope :not_sent_by, ->(user) { where.not(user: user) }
end
```

Note that we could write the *where*-condition of *with_user* directly in the *has_many* block, but this way we respect encapsulation: the *User* model knows nothing about the attributes of the *Conversation* table.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! Would this work for unread: 
` def unread 
  Messages.where(read: false)
end` 

And this for sender_user_not:
` def sender_user_not(user)
   self.where.not(user: user)
end`

Comment: Those are methods, you need scopes (class-methods, so `def self.xyx`). Note that you have `scope` classmethod for this. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes